# Balanced brackets

Tags: apex, algorithm

I need to implement a function that determines whether brackets are balanced. Here are a couple of examples of how it should work:
'' => true

'[]'  => true

'{}'  => true

'()   => true

'[[]' => false

']['  => false

'[[][][[]]]' => true

'[[][]][' => false

'{)' = false

'{[(<{[]}>)]}' = true

Signature is Boolean and it takes String as a parameter
I have found couple of videos of how it should be checked but it seems like there is no stack data structure in apex
https://youtu.be/9kmUaXrjizQ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two methods of Stack interface used for this execise are:

- `push()` - Adds an element to the top of the stack.
- `pop()` - Removes and returns the element at the top of the stack, which is the latest element pushed (added) into the stack.

You could achieve the same behavior using two methods of List:

- `add()` - Adds an element to the end of the list.
- `remove(index)` - Removes and return the element at the specified index.

In order to mimic the `Stack.pop()` behavior with `List.remove()`, you must always remove the element at the end of the list, so at index `list.size()-1`.

Instead of storing the opening bracket into the stack and writing several if-else when the character is a closing bracket, you could store the closing one. Moreover you could exit the cycle at the first error.

These advices translates in the following code

```
static Boolean balancedBrackets(String input) {
    // this map holds every characters you want to check
    // the keys are the opening brackets
    // the values ares the closing brackets
    Map<String, String> opening = new Map<String, String>();
    opening.put('(', ')');
    opening.put('[', ']');
    opening.put('{', '}');
    opening.put('<', '>');

    // This set is used to check whether a char is a closing bracket
    // Keep in mind that Set.contains() runs in constant time
    Set<String> closing = new Set<String>(opening.values());

    // This list will hold the closing bracket instead of the opening one
    // so the check when we'll find a closing bracket will be smooth
    List<String> stack = new List<String>();
    Boolean isValid = true;

    for (String character : input.split('')) {
        if (opening.containsKey(character)) {
            // if the current char is an opening bracket
            // the related closing bracket is added to the list
            stack.add(opening.get(character));
        } else if (closing.contains(character)) {
            // if the current char is a closing bracket
            // it must be equal to the last char added to the list
            String s = stack.isEmpty() ? null : stack.remove(stack.size()-1);
            if (character != s) {
                // otherwise the brackets aren't balanced and we can stop iterating over characters
                isValid = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // isValid is true only if the closing brackets are in the right order
    // the list is empty only if there is a closing bracket for every opening one 
    return isValid && stack.isEmpty();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a stack, called Apex.Stack. It is, however, undocumented and should not be relied on in production code. If you want to, though, you can always write your own stack:

```
public class Stack {
  Object[] values = new Object[0];
  public void push(Object value) {
    values.add(value);
  }
  public void pop() {
    return values.remove(values.size()-1);
  }
  public Boolean isEmpty() {
    return values.size() == 0;
  }
  public Integer size() {
    return values.size();
  }
  public void clear() {
    values.clear();
  }
}
```

Plus whatever other methods you think you might need. Unfortunately, we don't have templating yet, so you'll have to either cast or create concrete types based on your needs (e.g. IntegerStack, BooleanStack, etc).

Answer (score 0):

it can be solved in multiple ways :

```
public static void checkBalancedBrackets(String s){
    String ss =s;
    String ssnew;
    Integer i;
        
    for(i=0; i< s.length()-1; i++){
        System.debug('Length of string is:  ' + ss.length());
        ss=ss.remove('{}');
        ss=ss.remove('()');
        ss=ss.remove('<>');
        ss=ss.remove('[]');
        
        System.debug('New SS is:  ' + ss );             
        
        if (ssnew==ss)
            break;          
            
        ssnew=ss;
    }
        
    if(ss.length()>0){
        System.debug('its not a balanced string ');
    }
    else
        System.debug('It is balanced string');
}
```